# Помогите с задачей на питоне, я не поняла что тут нужно

Tags: python

На вход программы поступает последовательность целых чисел, каждое число на отдельной строке. Концом последовательности является число, которое больше либо равно 10000. В рамках данной задачи, нужно считать, что это последнее число не входит в последовательность. Напишите программу, которая выводит количество введенных чисел.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подается последовательность чисел, каждое число на отдельной строке.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести количество членов последовательности.

```
Sample Input 1:

1
2
3
9999
-2
12345

Sample Output 1:

5

Sample Input 2:

-200
100
1234
10000

Sample Output 2:

3

Sample Input 3:

10000

Sample Output 3:

0
```

Напишите программу. Тестируется через stdin → stdout

Comment: Нужно получать на вход строки с числами и считать их. Когда послупит число >= 10000 перестать принимать числа и напечатать значение счётчика.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
while int(input()) < 10000:
    i += 1

print(i)
```

Comment: интересно кто и за что минус поставил...

Comment: @n1tr0xs Потому что не надо отвечать на низкокачественные вопросы вероятно. Хотя я минус не ставил, просто предположение.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor `Потому что не надо отвечать на низкокачественные вопросы` - где в правилах про это написано? Или есть обсуждение на мете, где решили, что так не нужно делать?